# How to schedule delay message in activemq using python stomp.py client

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

I am using [python](/questions/tagged/python) [`sompt.py`](https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py) to access my `ActiveMQ` server.

I created client and send data. But I have to [Schedule Delay Message](http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html).

```
import time
import sys

import stomp

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        print('received an error "%s"' % message)
    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        print('received a message "%s"' % message)

conn = stomp.Connection()
conn.set_listener('', MyListener())
conn.start()
conn.connect('admin', 'password', wait=True)

conn.subscribe(destination='/queue/test', id=1, ack='auto')

conn.send(body=' '.join(sys.argv[1:]), destination='/queue/test')

time.sleep(2)
conn.disconnect()
```

I check JAVA example, where user can pass `headers`. `send` also take `headers` as argument in `stomp.py`, but I dont know which key I have to pass in it.

[`stomp.constants`](https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py/blob/master/stomp/constants.py) dont have any headers for delay.

Tried the `AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY` headers but seems not working.

```
import time
import sys

import stomp

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        print('received an error "%s"' % message)
    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        print "Time for message receive: %s", time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        print('received a message "%s"' % message)

conn = stomp.Connection()
conn.set_listener('', MyListener())
conn.start()
conn.connect(wait=True)

conn.subscribe(destination='/queue/test', id=1, ack='auto')

print "Time for send message: %s", time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
conn.send(body=' '.join(sys.argv[1:]), destination='/queue/test', headers={'AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY': 100000})

time.sleep(2)
conn.disconnect()
```

Output:

```
test@localhost$ python /tmp/test.py this is test
Time for send message: %s 14:03:34
Time for message receive: %s 14:03:34
received a message "this is test"
```

Comment: Just for other readers, yes you are doing the correct thing. As the discussion below, I believe the message broker did not enable scheduler.

Answer (score 3):

The values for sending scheduled messages over STOMP match the definitions of the values in the Java code for the broker, but as a quick reference you can look at the Apache NMS STOMP site for a quick [example](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/stomp-delayed-and-scheduled-message-feature.html).

The values are as follows:

```
"AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY" = delay in milliseconds
"AMQ_SCHEDULED_PERIOD" = repeat period in milliseconds
"AMQ_SCHEDULED_REPEAT" = repeat count
"AMQ_SCHEDULED_CRON" = cron entry such as "0 * * * *"
```

Comment: Hi Tim, but if we change this in `apache`, then it will apply to all messages? I need to send only few messages with `delay`, all other has to process with normal execution

Comment: I don't really understand your question, you put the headers on your STOMP messages when you want to apply delay, not sure what the apache thing your are asking is about

Comment: If I use `conn.send(...,..., headers={'AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY': 10})` then this will schedule my message to be delivered after `10` seconds ?

Comment: delay is set in milliseconds so no, it would delay it by 10 milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks @Tim I will try this solution.

Comment: Tim, I tried your solution, but seems its not working. I am running acitvemq in docker. I not changed anything in docker activemq container configuration.

Comment: Make sure scheduler support is enabled on the broker

Comment: Thanks. Last comment save my day.